# replace() with RegExp on array elements

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to write a JavaScript function which converts some simple BBcode Tags like [red] [/red] to Html-Tags. I think the replace() function is the best way to do it. I wrote a simple testfunction to try it, but it does not seem to work.

```
/**
* @function
* @description Replaces the bb-tags with html-tags
*/
function bbToHtml(form) {
    debugger

    var text = form.text.value;
    bbTags = new Array("[red]", "[yellow]", "[green]", "[/red]", "[/yellow]", "[/green]");
    htmlTags = new Array("<font color='red'>", "<font color='yellow'>", "<font color='green'>", "</font>", "<font>", "</font>");

    for (var i = 0; i < bbTags.length; i++) {
        var re = new RegExp(bbTags[i], "g");
        text = text.replace(re, htmlTags[i]);
    }

    alert(text);
}
```

It should convert `"[red]hello[/red]"` to `"<font color='red'>hello</font>"`, but it just gives me a weird string.

What is wrong? I think this has something to do with my regular expression.

Comment: Can you put your "It should convert"... in a code block - I think there are some html constructs there that don't show up in the question. Also, can you show what the "weird string" is?

Comment: Yeah, what's the weird string?

Comment: Its something like that, but longer: <f<f<fo</font>t><f<fo</font>t></font>t c<fo</font>t><fo</font>t><fo</font>t><<fo</font>t>f<fo</font>t></font>t>=\

Comment: Shouldn't the second `"<font>"` be `"</font>"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` and `]` have special meaning in regular expressions and need to be escaped, moreover you do not need regular expressions the way you've written your code and can just do:

```
function bbToHtml(form) {
    debugger

    var text = form.text.value;
    bbTags = new Array("[red]", "[yellow]", "[green]", "[/red]", "[/yellow]", "[/green]");
    htmlTags = new Array("<font color='red'>", "<font color='yellow'>", "<font color='green'>", "</font>", "<font>", "</font>");

    for (var i = 0; i < bbTags.length; i++) {
        while(text.indexOf(bbTags[i])!==-1){
            text = text.replace(bbTags[i], htmlTags[i]);
        }
    }

    alert(text);
}
```

Just to let you know, you can use array literals so instead of arrays. `new Array(comma seperated values)` is identical to `[comma seperated values]` in javascript. 
Also, you can use your array like a map in your case, for example:

```
var bbTagsToHTML = {}
bbTagsToHtml["[red]"] = "<font color='red'>"
```

and iterate through that.

If you would like you can escape your regular expressions too, please see [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript/494122#494122) for a function that does that.

You can also do that manually. `"[red]"` becomes `"\[red\]"` (the bracket escaped).

Comment: If you don't use a regexp, it will only replace the first match, not all the matches.

Answer (score 0):

just change this line

```
text = text.replace(re, htmlTags[i]);
```

into

```
text = text.replace(bbTags[i], htmlTags[i]);
```

removing unuseful code.

`replace` works also on 'normal' (not regex) values as argument.

Comment: But it only replaces the first match, not all matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with regex you can simplify *a lot*. No arrays or loops:

```
var str = '[red]foo[/red] hello world [blue]hey[/blue]',
    re = /\[(\w+)\](.*)\[\/\1\]/g;

str = str.replace(re, '<font color="$1">$2</font>');

console.log(str);
//^ <font color="red">foo</font> hello world <font color="blue">hey</font>
```

Also, as a side note, `font` is rarely used anymore I'd suggest you use a `span` with a class.